# how to deselect radio buttons with a different name

Tags: php, html

i have this form i made with radio buttons which every button got his own name. i need to give the user the option to select more than one radio button if he needs to, but i ran into a problem; after the user have chosen a radio he doesn't have the option to deselect it, which is very problematic for me. i don't know if this question has been asked before but i couldn't find one that matches mine.

the code -

```
<?php foreach($pics as $pic): ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="<?= $pic['pic_location'] ?>" /><a href="<?= URL::base() . 'image/' . $pic['pic_id'] ?>"><img src="<?= URL::base(). 'files/images/'. $pic['pic_location'] ?>" width="100" height="100"/></a>
                    <?php if($pic['pic_status'] === 'privet'): ?>
                        <a href="<?= URL::base() . 'public/' . $pic['pic_id'] ?>">make this photo public</a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <a href="<?= URL::base() . 'privet/' . $pic['pic_id'] ?>">make this photo private</a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?= Form::submit('delete selected photos') ?>
            <?= form::close() ?>
```

pay attention that the name is different for every radio button that is created with the 'foreach' loop. 
thank you for your time.

Comment: For that application, use check boxes instead of radio buttons.  You can style the check boxes so they look like buttons if that's important: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles

Comment: Is that a cms or a Framework what you using there.

Comment: i'm using a costume framework

Comment: and thank you, checkbox really did solve my problem. im not so familliar with all of the HTML elements haha.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using radio instead of checkboxes, but in case you really need the radio boxes, you can deselect with JS/jQuery:

```
$(this).prop('checked', false); // jQuery.
this.checked = false; // JS.
```

Comment: i forgot all about the checkbox element but someone mentioned it in the previous answers. anyway thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied my comment into an answer because it is possible to do what OP wanted without JavaScript and also get  the radio button effect if necessary.

For that application, use check boxes instead of radio buttons. You can style the check boxes so they look like buttons if that's important: cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles